# Issue in insertion to an array inside a struct

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I have issue in the following smartcontract.

I have defined a struct which includes an string array.
And I have defined a mapping for this struct.

```
struct Stonedetails {

        uint stoneweight;
        string stoneimagehash;
        string stoneidbywholesaledealer;
        string[] stoneidsbycutter;


}

mapping (uint=>Stonedetails) public stonedetailsTable;
```

I have stored the values in struct using the following methods inside a function by passing parameters.

```
 stonedetailsTable[stoneid].stoneweight =stoneweight;
 stonedetailsTable[stoneid].stoneimagehash =stoneimagehash;
 stonedetailsTable[stoneid].stoneidbywholesaledealer =stoneidbywholesaledealer;
```

How can I store the values in string array?
Is it the way to store the values one by one?

```
stonedetailsTable[stoneid1].stoneidsbycutter.push(stoneidbycuttervalue);
```

How can I find the length of array using stoneidsbycutter.length?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Is the code you shared not working? Is `stonedetailsTable[stoneid].stoneidsbycutter.length` not working?

Comment: @smarx I tried to find length ,but it returns value as '0'...Is the way of insertion I used is correct??

Comment: It looks okay to me. Can you share some full code that exhibits the problem? (E.g. a `push` followed by checking the `length`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct. I tested the following and got a length of 1 as expected:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Test {
    struct Stonedetails {
        uint stoneweight;
        string stoneimagehash;
        string stoneidbywholesaledealer;
        string[] stoneidsbycutter;
    }

    mapping (uint=>Stonedetails) public stonedetailsTable;

    function Test() public {
        stonedetailsTable[0].stoneidsbycutter.push("hello");
    }

    function getLength() public constant returns (uint256) {
        return stonedetailsTable[0].stoneidsbycutter.length; // returns 1
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked succesfully